# Filezilla Throttle File transfer rate not user

Tags: ftp, rate-limiting

Is it possible to throttle the file being transferred rather than a user.  We have lots of users using the same username/pw and need to throttle each session.  Is that possible?

Comment: Is this about FileZilla client or FileZilla server?

Comment: Fileserver Server